# Pass a variable to a RegExp with symbol JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to generate output like **Mr. X born on 01-01-2000** by using the following code

```
var str="%(name)s born on %(date)s",
replace={name:'Mr.X',date:'01-01-2000'},
subject=["name","date"];

subject.map(function(data){
   var regex = new RegExp("%("+data+")s", 'g');
   str=str.replace(regex,replace[data])
})

console.log(str);
```

I cant able to replace dynamic variable with symbol Any one help me to find better solution Thanks.

Comment: why do you want to use RegExp? I could write a simple function which generates such names and dates if you need this

Comment: That's not big deal, but I just research whether it is possible or not. i want to know regexp help us to solve this kind of scenario.

Comment: What about: `name + 's born on ' + date`?

Comment: @SharathiRB i would do it the way WashingtonGuedes told

Comment: @WashingtonGuedes then it will normal scenario i want to  do based on my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just escape `(` and `)` that has special meaning in regex, used for grouping (matches).

```
var regex = new RegExp("%\\("+data+"\\)s", 'g');
```

---

Running code:

```js
   var str="%(name)s born on %(date)s",
    replace={name:'Mr.X',date:'01-01-2000'},
    subject=["name","date"];

    subject.map(function(data){
       var regex = new RegExp("%\\("+data+"\\)s", 'g');
       str=str.replace(regex,replace[data])
    })

    document.write(str);
```

Comment: Thanks @Braj this is the correct solution i think it will help to some one.

Answer (score 1):

One problem is your regex isn't correct you must escape ( and ). You can also simplify your code like so:

```
var str="%(name)s born on %(date)s",
replace={name:'Mr.X',date:'01-01-2000'}
for(var key in replace) {
    var regex = new RegExp("%\\("+key+"\\)s", 'g');
    str=str.replace(regex,replace[key])
}
console.log(str);
```

You already have name and date stored as keys so why not use them. No need to create an array with "name" and "date"...

Output:

```
Mr.X born on 01-01-2000
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. In my scenario subject and replace variable value are getting from different resource so I just mention like that.

Answer (score 1):

`str.replace` + a callback should do the trick:

```js
var str="%(name)s born on %(date)s",
replace={name:'Mr.X',date:'01-01-2000'},


str = str.replace(/%\((\w+)\)s/g, function(_, id){
   return replace[id];
});

document.write(str);
```